# ios7 empty autolayout layout already ambiguous

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I just created an empty iOS Project for a 'Single View Application' which targets iOS7, but when i ran the empty project and inspected my viewtree by typing:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

i got the result that the two layout guides are already ambiguous

```
*<UIWindow:0x108f537f0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   *<UIView:0x109409850>
|   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x109409c10> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x10940a540> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
```

Is there a reason to get rid of those warnings - or can i simply ignore them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ignore them if you dont want to use Autolayout or go to the Interface Builder and add the layouts yourself (you can even let XCode add the layouts it thinks are needed)

[image]

Comment: i do want to use autolayout - but why are the 'autoadded' views already ambiguous?

Comment: Just go to the interface builder and let XCode add the suggested layouts, let me add a capture

Comment: thanks - i think its still weird that their own views are ambiguous, but it's nice to know i can ignore that.

Answer (score 5):

It was the same with iOS 6.

I guess it sometimes takes time for constraints to "settle down" and not be ambiguous. According to WWDC 2012 video "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout," ambiguity can be temporarily tolerated (unlike unsatisfiability, which immediately raises an exception).

If you want to prove to yourself that your constraints are not remaining ambiguous, then create a wrapper for [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace] and call it after a short delay:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 

    [self performSelector:@selector(wrapperForLoggingConstraints) withObject:nil afterDelay:.3];
}

- (void)wrapperForLoggingConstraints
{
    [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace];
}
```

You have to create a category on UIWindow in order to get this to work:

```
@interface UIWindow()

+ (UIWindow *)keyWindow;
- (NSString *)_autolayoutTrace;

@end
```

I put this category in its own header file, UIWindow_AutoLayoutDebug.h

Where ever I call [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace] in my app, I import UIWindow_AutoLayoutDebug.h

I learned about calling [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace] in code from the book "iOS 6 by tutorials", Volume 1, by the raywenderlich.com team. The idea of delaying the call is my own.

Comment: Can anybody verify that this trick is legit? I had several AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT warnings in a view after calling _autolayoutTrace in viewDidAppear. After calling _autolayoutTrace after a .3 second delay they're all gone. Just want to know if this can be trusted, I'm still learning auto layout and want to make sure I'm all good.

Comment: This won't work for me because it won't compile. You can only call _autolayoutTrace inside an lldb session. It won't compile as written above. You could call the UIView method 'hasAmbiguousLayout', but this tells you about a single view, not its decedents. To do that, one would write a method to recurse through all subviews and call hasAmbiguousLayout on each of them. Remember, for development time only, not for shipping code.

Comment: @idStar you have to create a category on UIWindow (see updated answer)

Comment: For me they are not gone, even if I put 1 second delay.

Comment: I am calling _autolayoutTrace from within a breakpoint after view has appeared -- and getting AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT on both UIWindow and UILayoutGuides.

Comment: @PhilMitchell Don't worry about the layout guides and the window; they're not your responsibility.